# any ubuntu touch for sony xperia t2 ultra(D5303)?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sony

I want to install Ubuntu touch on my Sony Xperia T2 device.Any Ubuntu touch for sony xperia t2 ultra(D5303)? When will Ubuntu Touch be available for this device?

Answer (score 0):

A list of supported devices are available at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices.

Your device, Xperia T2, is not explicitly mentioned but however, [Xperia T (mint)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/mint) is on the list. You may notice that most of the features are *Work in Progress* as of now.

As for your second question, try contacting the [maintainer](https://launchpad.net/~lalitmaganti) of the image for Xperia T.

Comment: Yes Xperia T(mint) is on the list. I already tested on my device. It's not work. Mint is not concerned with t2 device. I think that mint is only for Xperia T.